# creating socket.io server in protractor test

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, protractor

I'm trying to create a protractor tests to my angular front-end which is connecting to a socket.io server. In my testing I'm opening a new socket.io server and closing it at the end of the test, but i found out that callback of the old test is still running instead of the new one.
What am I doing wrong?

My simplified protractor code:

```
var Server = require('socket.io');

describe('test', function () {
    var io;

    beforeEach(function () {
        io = Server(3800);
        var test = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description;
        io.on('connection', function () {
            var current = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description;
            if (test !== current) {
                // This line shouldn't run
                console.error('Connection been made to server of test ' + test +
                    ' while current test is test ' + current);
            }
        });
    });

    it('one', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
        var label = element(By.binding('status'));
        expect(label.getText()).toBe('connected');
    });

    it('two', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
        var label = element(By.binding('status'));
        expect(label.getText()).toBe('connected');
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        io.close();
    })
});
```

and my simplified angular-app:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('test', [])
                .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                    var socket = io('localhost:3800');
                    socket.on('connect', function () {
                        $scope.status = 'connected';
                        $scope.$digest();
                    })
                })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        {{ status }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `io.close()` is probably asynchronous, so the `afterEach` completes before the `io` is actually closed (and then the next one presumably fails to start because the port is already in use, etc, etc).  Maybe you can teach Protractor to wait for the Server to be completely done (or maybe teach `beforeEach` to retry if it gets socket-in-use errors.)  (Though you should verify `io.close()` is really the problem first.)

Answer (score 2):

As P.T. mentioned you should wait for connection to open and close before moving to the next block.

```
describe('test', function () {


    beforeEach(function (done) { //wait for me
        var that = this;
        this.io = Server(3800);
        this.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            that.activeSocket = socket;
            done(); //ready
        });
    });

    it('one', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
        var label = element(By.binding('status'));
        expect(label.getText()).toBe('connected');
    });

    it('two', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
        var label = element(By.binding('status'));
        expect(label.getText()).toBe('connected');
    });

    afterEach(function (done) {
        this.io.close();
        this.activeSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
          done();
        });

    })
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. yet had a timeout in the "beforeEach" function which I solved by moving the browser.get to the "beforeEach".
but i still getting timeouts since the activeSocket never disconnects.

Comment: Still getting jasmine timeout.
(edited your code and moved browser get to afterEach)